# What other ways can I write this loop?

Tags: loops

I am still a beginner and I’m just wondering if my loop has any other ways I can write it for learning sake. Here is my loop:

```
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(index >= 0 && index < arr.length && count < 100){
        index = arr[index];
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which includes *every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `for loop` for that mission, so you can write:

```
for (int count = 0, index = 0; index >= 0 && index < arr.length && count < 100 ;count++)
{
        index = arr[index];
}
```

but notice that in your for loop, you are not updating the value of `index`, by which I mean that `index` is always 0 even in your original code

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative in this case would be a for loop.  As you'll notice while coding when using multiple conditions to a loop it is best to use a for loop because it will look much neater and for loops already require three conditions perfect for your case.

```
    while ( condition && condition && condition) 
              vs 
      for ( condition ; condition ; condition)
```